# power bi load rows based on condition in Query editor

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the blow data

```
create table #tbl (Continet varchar(40),    Country varchar(40),    City varchar(40),   OrderDate date)
insert into #tbl values
('South America',   'Colombia', 'Angostura',    '2020-05-13'),
('Europe','Germany','Thuringia','2019-02-12'),
('Asia','China','Tianjin','2017-11-22'),
('Asia','India ','Hyderabad','2018-02-15'),
('Asia','China','Tianjin','2016-10-30'),
('Europe','United Kingdom', 'Northwich','2015-05-03')
select * from #tbl
drop table #tbl
```

I am taking the data to power BI and the rows are in millions.
what i want is to Filter the data in Power BI query editor to load only India Data. The data is from google analytics, for simplicity i use sql to give the above data. How can i do it in power query editor
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know what a sql `view` is.

Make an sql `view` -with a proper `where`- and feed `power-bi` with its result.

Comment: it is from google analytic so creating view is not possible

Comment: Can't you write a `where` in a `select`?

Comment: no I cannot because the data is not from SQL, I use SQL to give an example

Comment: I am not an expert, in fact the contrary, but I thought, `Big Query` was the language to export data from analytics. And `Big Query` is an `sql` based language.